# Multiple MSIs installation using embedded EmbeddedChainer

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am trying to install multiple .msi(s) using a Windows Installer Embedded chain. I researched some information from a website and I tried it. But it doesn't work (**WiX + C#**).

1. When I checked the debug, it works successfully until `transaction.Commit()` and `transaction.close()`. But `SampleApp.msi` didn't install.
2. 'Multiple MISs Installer' installed successfully even if `SampleApp.msi` didn't work, and I can't uninstall 'Multiple MISs Installer'. The entry in the  error log is "fatal error during installation".

How do I fix it?

**Multiple MSIs Installer\Product.wxs**

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="Multiple Installer">
            <Component Id="InstallMSIComponent" Guid="{7091DE57-7BE3-4b0d-95D5-07EEF6463B62}">
                <File Id="FILE_MprjChainer.exe" Name="MprjChainer.exe"
                      Source="C:\A_VS2008\WiX\MprjChainer\MprjChainer\bin\Debug\MprjChainer.exe"
                      DiskId="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
                <File Id="Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll"
                      Name="Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll"
                      Source="C:\Program Files\Windows Installer XML v3.5\SDK\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll" />
                <File Id="System.dll"
                      Name="System.dll"
                      Source="C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll" />
                <File Id="System.Core.dll" Name="System.Core.dll"
                      Source="C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Core.dll" />
                <File Id="System.Windows.Forms.dll" Name="System.Windows.Forms.dll"
                       Source="C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Windows.Forms.dll" />
                <File Id="System.Xml.dll"
                      Name="System.Xml.dll"
                      Source="C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Xml.dll" />
                <File Id="System.Xml.Linq.dll"
                      Name="System.Xml.Linq.dll"
                      Source="c:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll" />
                <RemoveFolder Id="INSTALLLOCATION" On="uninstall"/>
            </Component>

            <Component Id="CMPG_SimpleApp" Guid="{CB568AA4-9790-4efd-91BB-82682F063321}">
                <File Id="SimpleApp.msi"
                      Name="SimpleApp.msi"
                      Source="C:\A_VS2008\WiX\MSIs\SimpleApp.msi"
                      DiskId="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
            </Component>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Directory>

<EmbeddedChainer Id="Chainer" FileSource="FILE_MprjChainer.exe"/>

<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="MPrjInstaller" Level="1">
    <ComponentRef Id="InstallMSIComponent"/>
    <ComponentRef Id="CMPG_SimpleApp"/>
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="Product.Generated" />
</Feature>
```

**Chainer\CustonAction.cs**

```
namespace MprjChainer
{
    public class CustomActions
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

            try
            {
                IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt32(args[0], 16));
                Transaction transaction = Transaction.FromHandle(ptr, true);

                transaction.Join(TransactionAttributes.JoinExistingEmbeddedUI);

                transaction.Commit();
                transaction.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("e.Message; " + e.Message);
                throw e;
            }
        }

        [CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult CustomAction1(Session session)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
            session.Log("Begin CustomAction1");

            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling InstallProduct():

```
transaction.Join(TransactionAttributes.JoinExistingEmbeddedUI);

// start another installation in the same transaction
Installer.InstallProduct(@"path_To_Your_MSI", arguments);   
// it's good to include /l*v install.log in the arguments so that you'll get a verbose log of the installation

transaction.Commit();
```

An example of Embedded Chainer can be seen at:  [WiX EmbeddedChainer Examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272718/wix-embeddedchainer-examples)

You could also look at Burn (the bootstrapper/chainer from Wix) for chaining multiple msi packages: http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2009/7/14/Lets-talk-about-Burn

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the c# code:
In the line "IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt32(args[0], 16));" the "16" must be a "10"!

Otherwise you will get "bad handle" errors when there are more than 10 transactions (e.g. when there are five or more sub msi's called from the embedded chainer).